# Video concatenating, with overlay

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, libav, avisynth

I have a video recorded from a gopro which is split into 3 parts as the maximum filesize is reached after about 17 minutes and the gopro automatically splits it into multiple parts.
I also have a camstudio recording of my desktop.

I need to concatenate the 3 gopro videos, and also overlay the camstudio recording as a picture in picture sort of view.

I.e it would end up as below where the 9 is the overlay and 1,2,3 are the gopro videos

999999999999999

111111222222333

I have to perform this on a regular basis (and multiple videos), so looking to write a batch file to generate the desired output, in a format playable by windows media player with no downloaded codecs. Reducing the filesize to about 1gb/45min at a maximum would be useful as well.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in FFmpeg or libav? I can do the concatenation OR the overlay in FFmpeg but cant seem to get both. Maybe I just need to perform the concatenation first to a temporary file then use that as the input for the overlay?

Currently I am using the following 2 commands in ffmpeg to achieve this, but the filesize is huge and the quality isnt great, plus it takes a long time. 
Currently the output is at about 1gb for 7 minutes but my videos can be up to 45 minutes, so I really need to cut the file size down preferably to around 1-2gb for 45 minutes

```
ffmpeg -i concat:1.mp4|2.mp4|3.mp4" -an -q:v 9 -preset veryslow -crf 28 -vcodec wmv2 temp.wmv
ffmpeg -i temp.wmv -an -vf"movie=overlay.avi, scale=iw:ih; [in][small] overlay =0:0 [out]" -q:v 9 -preset veryslow -crf 28 -vcodec wmv2 output.wmv
```

The output from ffmpeg concat is:

```
>ffmpeg -i "concat:GOPR0133.mp4|GP010133.mp4|GP020133.mp4" -an -q:v 9 -vcodec wm
v2 70-70KMtemp.wmv
ffmpeg version N-61191-gea9399f Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar  8 2014 22:01:33 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 66.101 / 52. 66.101
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 027c29c0] Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'concat:GOPR0133.mp4|GP010133.mp4|GP0201
33.mp4':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:47:21
    minor_version   : 0
    major_brand     : avc1
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
  Duration: 00:17:24.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 71321 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709
), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30002 kb/s, 100 fps, 100 tbr, 180k tbn, 200 tbc
(default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:47:21
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:47:21
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
[swscaler @ 036088a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range
correctly
Output #0, asf, to '70-70KMtemp.wmv':
  Metadata:
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    minor_version   : 0
    major_brand     : avc1
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf55.34.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:
1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:47:21
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> wmv2)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=9.0 size=      60kB time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=8195.6kbits/s
frame=   15 fps= 14 q=9.0 size=     132kB time=00:00:00.15 bitrate=7203.6kbits/s
frame=   25 fps= 16 q=9.0 size=     207kB time=00:00:00.25 bitrate=6779.7kbits/s
frame=   33 fps= 16 q=9.0 size=     235kB time=00:00:00.33 bitrate=5834.4kbits/s
frame=   39 fps= 15 q=9.0 size=     294kB time=00:00:00.39 bitrate=6183.9kbits/s
frame=   47 fps= 15 q=9.0 Lsize=     326kB time=00:00:00.47 bitrate=5677.5kbits/
s
etc....
```

Then the output I get when doing the overlay

```
>ffmpeg -i GOPR0131.mp4 -an -vf "movie=20140417_0930_55.avi, scale=iw:ih [small]
; [in][small] overlay =0:0 [out]" -q:v 9 -preset veryslow -crf 28 37-38KM.wmv
ffmpeg version N-61191-gea9399f Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar  8 2014 22:01:33 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 66.101 / 52. 66.101
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GOPR0131.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:29:13
  Duration: 00:11:59.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709
), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30005 kb/s, 100 fps, 100 tbr, 180k tbn, 200 tbc
(default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:29:13
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:29:13
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
Codec AVOption preset (Set the encoding preset (cf. x264 --fullhelp)) specified
for output file #0 (37-38KM.wmv) has not been used for any stream. The most like
ly reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or th
at it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any st
ream.
Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for
output file #0 (37-38KM.wmv) has not been used for any stream. The most likely r
eason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that i
t is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream
.
[swscaler @ 0401a560] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range
correctly
Output #0, asf, to '37-38KM.wmv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf55.34.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 1
280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-17 09:29:13
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> msmpeg4)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=9.0 size=      23kB time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=3075.9kbits/s
frame=   16 fps= 15 q=9.0 size=      57kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=2913.4kbits/s
frame=   25 fps= 16 q=9.0 size=      91kB time=00:00:00.25 bitrate=2991.0kbits/s
frame=   32 fps= 15 q=9.0 Lsize=     113kB time=00:00:00.32 bitrate=2898.9kbits/
s
etc...
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more info about what codecs/format the GoPro and your desktop recordings have? Also, playing in WMP without additional codecs is tricky unless you run a recent version of Windows. Full backwards-compatibility with, say Windows XP, can only be achieved by selecting an inefficient codec.

Comment: Sure, the desktop recording is done by camstudio and is using camstudio lossless codec 1.5.
The gopro camera records in MPEG4 (.mp4) files using h.264 compression.

I can live without backward compatibility to XP, as long as it is able to be played in media player on windows 7 with nothing additional installed (company is strict on this)

Comment: Also just edited the original question to show what I am currently doing

Comment: Thanks! It'd be great if you could show the full command line output as well. That way we can see what's going on.

Comment: Sure I have tried to edit it into my question (sorry if its messy, am new to this)

Comment: If it helps the gopro is using the lowest setting (720p = 1280x720 pixels (16:9)) - but the video will be watched in media player so I dont know if its possible to lower the resolution to bring down the file size while still looking good quality on a computer monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`setpts`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts), [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [`concat`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat), [`overlay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay), and [`format`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filters. I'm going to assume all inputs are 1280x720 since the size of the file you want to overlay is currently unknown.

## Example

```
ffmpeg -i gopro0.mp4 -i gopro1.mp4 -i gopro2.mp4 -i over.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [3:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=iw/4:-2[fg]; \
 [v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[bg][a]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=W-w-10:10,format=yuv420p[v]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

## What each filter does

- `setpts` makes the timestamps start at 0 which is recommended by `concat` and `overlay`.
- `scale` will make `over.avi` a smaller frame size.
- `concat` will concatenate each input.
- `overlay` will place the scaled `over.avi` in the top-right corner with a padding of 10 pixels. Refer to the [`overlay` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for additional options regarding inputs that have different durations (`shortest` and `eof_action` specifically).
- `format` will ensure that your output uses a chroma subsampling scheme that is compatible with all players (assuming you are using the encoder `libx264` which is default for MP4 if it is supported by your `ffmpeg` build).

## Notes

- If you want the output to have a smaller frame size, then add another `scale`:

  ```
  [bg][fg]overlay=W-w-10:10,scale=640:-2,format=yuv420p[v]"
  ```
- I was unable to test these examples at this time, so leave a comment if anything does not work as expected and I will look at it on Sunday unless others provide additional help.
- [File types supported by Windows Media Center (Windows 7)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-types-supported-media-center#1TC=windows-7) is next to worthless since it does not provide specifics, so you may have to experiment, or others that are more familiar with Windows 7 can edit this answer.

Comment: Thats great thankyou works perfectly. The output is a much better quality, and smaller file size, and the process runs much faster than what I had managed on my own.